# Question about transform on digits

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help with a problem.

Forvany positive integer m, let u be its units digit and t be it's number to tens, that is, the integer obtained when u is removed from m. So m=10t+u.

For any positive digit, c, the c-transform of m is the number t + cu. For example, the 2-transfrom of 2014 is 201+2 x 4 = 209.

Starting with any positive integer we can build a sequence of numbers where each number after the first is the c-transform of the number before it. We stop when a number is first repeated. For example, the 2-transform from 2014 is 2014, 209,38,19,19.

A positive integer is called c-tu if the last two terms in its c-transform sequence are the same, so 19 is a 2-terminator.

a)Show that 2015 is not 2-ti.

b)Find all c-terminators for all values of c.

c)Find all values of c for which 2015 is c-tu.

d)Describe exactly all numbers that are 2-ti.

Comment: Is c-tu the same as 2-terminator? Is 2-ti the same as 2-tu? If not, what is it? What class has this as homework, please?

Comment: What does "c-ti" mean? (as opposed to "c-tu", which appears to mean "c-terminator" from context.

Answer (score 1):

a) Just do the calculus and you will see a cycle coming twice starting with 8.

b) 
$$
t+cu = m = 10t+u\\
9t = (c-1)u
$$
hence 
$$
c=2, m=19\\
c=3, m=29\\
c=4, m=13,26,39\\
c=5, m=49\\
c=6, m=59\\
c=7, m=23,46,69\\
c=8, m=79\\
c=9, m=89\\
c=10, m=11,22,33,44,55,66,77,88,99\\
c=19, m=21,42,63,84\\
c=28, m=31,62,93\\
c=37, m=41,82\\
c=46, m=51\\
c=55, m=61\\
c=64, m=71\\
c=73, m=81\\
c=82, m=91\\
$$

c)
$$
2015 = 201*10+5 \to 201+5c
$$or c is either even or odd so

c is even ($c=2k$) : $201+5c = 201+10k$
c is odd ($c=2k+1$): $201+5c = 201+10k+5$

then

c is even : $201+5c \to 20+k+2k = 20+3k$
c is odd : $201+5c \to 20+k+6(2k+1) = 26+13k$

I don't know how to simplify this so the following solution might be bigger.

c is even : c=4,28
c is odd : c={}

d)
I'll edit if I find something.